# woocommerce add notes under a field on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need some help from Woocommerce ninjas out there.

Is there any way to put some text under fields on woocommerce checkout page?

[image]

I know some filter hook I might use but no options like `footnote`...

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     // something like footnote???
     $fields['billing_first_name']['footnote'] = 'little footnote text right here!!';
     return $fields;
}
```

Any idea??

Comment: WooCommerce filters do not support displaying content below the `<input>` fields. You might be able to use the `placeholder` attribute (which the filter does support), or use JavaScript to inject the required HTML after any elements that need the additional notes.

Comment: oh why didnt I think of that!, Javascript sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

Try 'description' instead of 'footnote':

```
$fields['billing_first_name']['description'] = 'footnote text';
```

Note that this text will be escaped using `esc_html`, so using HTML tags can be tricky.

As an alternative, you might want to try overriding the `woocommerce_form_field_` filter (e.g. `woocommerce_form_field_text`, see `includes/wc-template-functions.php` from the WooCommerce plugin). Sample:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_text', function ($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    if ($key === 'billing_first_name') {
        $field .= 'footnote text <a href="/">with link</a>';
    }

    return $field;
}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: Using `description` is actually working. It even works with HTML tags so no problem there. It will disappear when lost focus of field. But this can be customized with css and/or js. The option with using the action hook `woocommerce_form_field_text` is no footnote, but this can also be customized using css and order. Should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want plain text maybe you could use CSS :after and target the paragraph field id?
for example:

```
#billing_first_name_field:after {
content: "your footnote text";
font-size: 14px;
color: red;
}
```